# Side by Side information and Picture in Resume

Tags: tables, graphics, xcoffins

[image: Sample]
I'm trying to convert my resume made with Office to Latex. I wish to have my institute logo and then my information this way.

I am using this to do so:

```tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}    % Paper Size
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\raggedbottom   
\raggedright    
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Images support
\graphicspath{ {./assets/} }    % Path to images
\usepackage{multirow}       % Columns spanning multiple rows (https://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/tables)
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}       % Support hrefs

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}        % Horizontal (column) spacing; Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}  % Vertical (row) spacing; Default value: 1
\vfuzz=2in                          % Suppress vertical threshold warnings
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l }
    \multirow{3}{*}{\raisebox{-0.5in}{\includegraphics[width=0.63in, height=0.63in]{NITT}}}
    & \textbf{S. P. Sharan} & \textbf{Major : ECE $|$ Minor : Computer Appl.} \\
    & \textbf{National Institute of Technology Tiruchirappalli} & \textbf{B. Tech. $3^{rd}$ Year} \\
    & \textbf{GitHub : \href{https://github.com/Syzygianinfern0}{https://github.com/Syzygianinfern0}} & \textbf{Mail ID : \href{mailto:spsharan2000@gmail.com}{spsharan2000@gmail.com}} \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result. Although I am quite fine with the result, I don't have control over the image size and this feels like a really hacky way to do so.
[image]

What is a better way to do the same?

Comment: Also loading adjustbox` with option `[export]`` , you can use `\includegraphics[scale=…,valign=m ]` and choose the scaling that you please. You also can play with optional argument of `\multirow`, to adjust the vertical position. No `\raisebox` is required for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to do it without hacking or guessing.

[image: c]

You put the 3 elements that make up the header (a logo plus two tables) in boxes. Then assemble the boxes taking into account their relative positions and alignment.

All of this can be accomplished using the package `xcoffin` that behaves as a graphic layout program (boxes + relative positioning).

For convenience, I defined 3 lengths: the lateral side of the logo, its offset towards the left margin, and the separation between the three elements.

The assembly is done using a collector box (`\Framex`), joining the boxes one to the other while keeping their horizontal alignment

The expressions like `(\tablesep,0pt)` indicates the `(X,Y)`  offsets of the element being joined with respect to the other.

You can change the defined lengths, including the size of the logo, and see how the design adjusts on its own.

I assumed that you set a very small margin to be able to place the logo near the upper left corner. You don't need to do this now, because the package allows you to place "stuff" anywhere on the physical page, so I chose more standard margins.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}    % Paper Size
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\raggedbottom   
\raggedright    
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Images support
\graphicspath{ {./assets/} }    % Path to images
%\usepackage{multirow}       % Columns spanning multiple rows (https://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/tables)
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}       % Support hrefs

\usepackage{xcoffins} %needed
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\NewCoffin\Framex %collector box
\NewCoffin\Logox
\NewCoffin\MidTable
\NewCoffin\RightTable

\newlength{\logoside}
\newlength{\logoindent}
\newlength{\tablesep}

\setlength{\logoindent}{-0.3in} %shift the  logo into the left margin half its size
\setlength{\logoside}{0.6in} % size of the logo
\setlength{\tablesep}{0.1in} % horizontal separation between elements

% filling the boxes with its content
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Logox{\includegraphics[width=\logoside, height=\logoside]{example-grid-100x100pt}} 

\SetHorizontalCoffin\MidTable{%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}  
\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{l}
    S. P. Sharan \\
    National Institute of Technology Tiruchirappalli  \\
    GitHub : \href{https://github.com/Syzygianinfern0}{https://github.com/Syzygianinfern0}\\    
\end{tabular}   
}   

\SetHorizontalCoffin\RightTable{%   
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\bfseries       
\begin{tabular}{l}
    Major: ECE $|$ Minor: Computer Appl. \\
    B. Tech. $\mathbf{3^{rd}}$ Year \\
    Mail ID : \href{mailto:spsharan2000@gmail.com}{spsharan2000@gmail.com} \\
\end{tabular}   
}
%***********************************    

% assembling the boxes ************
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,vc]\Logox[l,vc](\logoindent, -\topmargin)
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[\Logox-r,\Logox-vc]\MidTable[l,vc](\tablesep,0pt)
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[\MidTable-r,\MidTable-vc]\RightTable[l,vc](\tablesep,0pt)
%%***********************

\begin{document}
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\Framex % type set the assembled set in the header space of the first page

\kant[1-7]  

\end{document}
```

The package offer just a few commands and it is very easy to learn and apply.

https://ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins?lang=en